# BULK INSERT from CSV into SQL Server (0 row(s) affected)

Tags: sql-server, csv

Here sample csv

```
"F","00004","GSP"
"X","00000","HPM-KRW","N","ADM","GLA","CCS","CC","WBS ELS","WBS EL","IOS","IO","KS","KC","X"
"X","00001","HPM-KRW","N","ADM","GLA","CCS","CC","WBS ELS","WBS EL","IOS","IO","KS","KC","X"
"X","00002","HPM-KRW","N","ADM","GLA","CCS","CC","WBS ELS","WBS EL","IOS","IO","KS","KC","X"
"X","00003","HPM-KRW","N","ADM","GLA","CCS","CC","WBS ELS","WBS EL","IOS","IO","KS","KC","X"
```

My table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ITFC_COMBO_DATA]
(
    [RECORD_TYPE] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [SEQUENCE] [char](5) NULL,
    [COMPANY_CODE] [char](35) NULL,
    [COMBO_RULE] [char](4) NULL,
    [GL_ACCOUNT_SET] [char](24) NULL,
    [GL_ACCOUNT] [char](10) NULL,
    [COST_CENTER_SET] [char](24) NULL,
    [COST_CENTER] [char](10) NULL,
    [WBS_ELEMENT_SET] [char](24) NULL,
    [WBS_ELEMENT] [char](24) NULL,
    [INTERNAL_ORDER_SET] [char](24) NULL,
    [INTERNAL_ORDER] [char](12) NULL,
    [KEYCODE_SET] [char](24) NULL,
    [KEY_CODE] [char](18) NULL,
    [INACTIVE] [char](1) NULL
)
```

My query looks like this

```
BULK INSERT ITFC_COMBO_DATA
    FROM 'C:\SFTP\Combo.csv' 
    WITH
    (   
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '","',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '"0x0a',
        FIRSTROW = 2
    )
```

I'm confused why always returns

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

I want the result in database without double quote ("") and no "F" row. because "F" row just identifier in CSV but "F" cannot be remove.

Help me thank you.

Comment: you can directly import by using **IMPORT DATA** - Inbuilt functionality of SSMS. and then you can update the column values.

Comment: @rajashmpanchal  Thank you for your answer, but Sory I must using store procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go thru below link,

[How to remove unwanted Quotation Marks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file.aspx)

[Read this for - How SQL Server interprets the quoted comma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485(v=sql.100).aspx)

This can help you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i had try your suggestion but the result it's same.

Comment: see I have one alternative, please make excel file of it and then try. will also try soon.